# Unable to update to latest version or curl

Tags: linux, installation, command-line-interface, redhat, curl

I need to install curl version 7.18.0 or later but when I run

```
yum install curl-devel
```

I get

```
Package curl-devel-7.15.5-2.1.el5_3.5.i386 already installed and latest version
```

How can I get it to install a version that is 7.18.0 or later?

OS from running

```
cat /proc/version
```

Linux version 2.6.18-128.2.1.el5.028stab064.4 (root@rhel5-64-build) (gcc version 4.1.2 20070626 (Red Hat 4.1.2-14)) #1 SMP Mon Jul 27 12:45:01 MSD 2009

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have installed the latest version that has been configured, tested and verified to work with your distro.

Instead of using Yum, you will need to download the latest version from http://curl.haxx.se/download.html and roll it yourself.

Have a nice evening.

QWade